# Servlet filter url mapping

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, url-pattern

How can a filter be mapped to the root of a URL?  I'm using Tomcat 7.0.2 and deploying an application as ROOT.war.  The welcome page is sign_in.xhtml.  I would like to run a filter whenever the client sends a request for the root of the site (i.e. the domain name only), or when the the client requests sign_in.xhtml. Here is what I have so far:

```
  <filter>
        <filter-name>My filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.myApp.myFilter</filter-class>        
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>My filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/sign_in.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Requests for sign_in.xhtml directly, successfully invoke the filter, but I'm not sure how to get requests for the root to invoke the filter.  According to the Servlet spec (version 3.0)

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

maps to the default servlet, and an empty string maps to the root.  Here's the relevant section from the spec:

"The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the
application's context root, i.e., requests of the form http://host:port//. In this case the path info is ’/’ and the servlet path and context path is
empty string (““)."

However, both of the following url patterns cause Tomcat to throw an exception.

```
<url-pattern></url-pattern>
<url-pattern>""</url-pattern>
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this. Thank You.

Andrew

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` should work for requests on the root. Did you try it?

If your intent is more to filter **all** requests, then you should use `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`.

---

**Update**: To exclude one and other, I tested the `url-pattern` of `/` at Tomcat 7 (using both `web.xml` and `@WebFilter(urlPatterns={"/"})`) and it indeed didn't work as expected. The `url-pattern` of `/` however works as expected on Tomcat 6 (Servlet 2.5) and also on Glassfish v3 (Servlet 3.0). I suspect a bug in Tomcat 7, so I've reported [issue 49914](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49914) about this.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this BalusC.  I'm intending to force redirection if the user is required to change their password.  A filter seems like the proper solution.  I guess I'll have to wait for 7.0.3 or come up with something different.  Any ideas?

Comment: A filter listening on `/*` which takes action only if the request URI is empty.

Comment: I'll give it a go and then update the url-patten once the Tomcat bug is fixed.

Comment: @Balus - I have the exact problem now - I am using Tomcat7 and wants to forward all calls with the request URL empty (www.mysite.com) to servlet. But if the URI is not empty - it shouldn't direct it to the servlet. I am using tomcat 7.9.16 - which way shall I do it?

Comment: @Odelya: Map a filter on `/*` and determine `HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI()` yourself. If the URI is empty, dispatch to `/` by `RequestDispatcher#forward()`, else just continue the filter chain.

Comment: @Balus - how does it influence performance to go on my filter?

Comment: @Odelya: That extra `if-else` check? It's fully negligible.

Comment: @BalusC <<The `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` should work for requests on the root.>> No it does not, for Tomcat 6 (Servlet 2.5). Any update re this topic?