# Mapping filter to the context-root of webapp in Tomcat7

Tags: java, jsp, filter, servlet-3.0

I am making a small webapp (this may be considered a uni task). My tools are java7, tomcat7.0.40.

I have a filter, called FlowFilter. Here is the definition and mapping for FlowFilter in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>FlowFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>path.to.filter.FlowFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FlowFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.flow</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.request</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>    
</filter-mapping>
```

My webapp root is at: http://[host]/mywebapp .

I also have a welcome file configured through web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

As seen from the mapping, I need FlowFilter to execute exactly in the following 3 situations:

1. When the request ends with ".flow"
2. When the request ends with ".request"
3. When i access http://[host]/mywebapp ("" mapping).

The problem is that FlowFilter is never invoked in the third case.

As I've read in the servlet-3 spec, 12.2 and 6.2.4, url-pattern rules apply to filters.

But as i debugged Tomcat's ApplicationFilterFactory.matchFiltersURL, url-patterns of filters are never matched against "" mapping.

The question is: is it that just Tomcat hasn't yet implemented such feature, or I misread the spec or I map filter in the wrong way, and why.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have defined a `<welcome-file-list>` this [will beat the filter](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49914#c3).

You could remove the `<welcome-file-list>` and redirect on your own after applying your filter-rules. And try to use `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` for matching the context-root.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686420/servlet-filter-url-mapping/3687003#3687003).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I understand why it fails. Shame that I read both this bug and answer before but inattentively. So, just let me clarify that once more, when the spec says: _"When processing a <filter-mapping> element using the <url-pattern> style, the
container must determine whether the <url-pattern> matches the request URI using the path mapping rules defined in Chapter 12, “Mapping Requests to Servlets”"_, it is implicitly implied that filter patterns are applied only after welcome-files are applied, so "" mapping rule becomes inapplicable to filters, right?

Comment: As I understood Mark Thomas the spec is a little bit unclear here. I have not read the whole spec so it's hard for me to say what the real intention is ;)

All I know from testing is that the mapping "" seems to be working for Servlets but not for Filters. And the mapping "/" is working for Filters as long as there is no welcome-file-list defined.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand your point. I think it is as clear for me, as it is for you in this case.

Comment: Also you should be aware of index.jsp or index.html files in webapp folder: contaier marks them as welcome-files by default, and it also prevents filter from working.